# mysql - make sum of all entries and then compare it with a value

Tags: mysql

**Hello everyone,**

(first of all, apologies for a noobish question)

Here is , what I'm trying to do, select couple of entries in **items_db** and then make a sum of all 
**buy_price** entries and then make sure that the sum(buy_price) >= 100.

**items_db:**

```
+---------+---------------+
| item_id | buy_price     |
+---------+---------------+
|      14 |             0 |
|      74 |            10 |
|      78 |             5 |
+---------+---------------+
```

So far I have only been able to select some entries and make a simple sum.

```
select sum(buy_price) from items_db where item_id in (14,74,78)
```

Now if I understand it correctly , **sum()** is an aggregate function so I can't just add a where clause at the end and check if the sum(..) >= 100. I'm not sure now whether I should goup all the entries somehow or use some other function to make ti all work?

Can anyone please advise me on what's the easiest way to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I think you need to give us more info because there are multiple ways to do it. As @Strawberry pointed out in your example it doesn't hit 100; then what? Since you admitted to being a noob (no shame - we all were at some pt), I'd recommend reading up on subqueries and CASE. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the sum aggregate function and an alias as you did, you can compare that alias with the having clause:

```
select sum(buy_price) as price from items_db where item_id in (14,74,78) having price > 100
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I swear I tried this too but it didn't work. .obviously I must have had some other issue in my select ... this one works exactly as I want to. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

[HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) clause has to help you.